# PhpStorm terminal window formatting/ ANSI color codes

Tags: laravel, terminal, console, phpstorm, ansi-escape

I'm new to PhpStorm and started creating application with Laravel.

I have one small difficulty with terminal. I use Windows 10 and the newest PhpStorm (2016.3). And as you can see, format of the artisan commands are highly unreadable.

Please help me, if you have any solutions/plugins to fix that. It would be also great to find some colour themes. Unless I have to customize it one by one in settings?

My window is on the left, on the right side is an screen from my teachers videos (he uses Mac).

[image]

Comment: check if terminal plugin is installed. Settings->Plugins

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is solution that works for me.

http://jasonkarns.com/blog/ansi-color-in-windows-shells/

In PhpStorm just replace Shell path and it works correctly!